# webserver and endianness of files

Tags: c, webserver, endianness

Let assume that the webserver support only HTTP 1.1 running on a little endian machine.

A random web-browser client request the file: test.txt. The file happens to be UTF-16BE encoded.

The developer of the webserver made the server with C programming language and decided to read the file in binary mode.

Eg. fopen("test.txt","rb")

The developer store all the bytes from the file inside array to remove the bom if needed.

My questions are as follows:

Should the developer convert the endianess or even remove the bom of the file before sending it to the client?

If not how does webserver like NGINX do ?

What if the requested file was a image of png type instead ?

And what if the server was running on big endian machine ?

I hope someone can help me in answering all my questions so i don't have more doubts...

Comment: File formats like PNG strictly define their own endianness, so there's no issue there--just send the bytes you get. UTF-16 is one of the few cases where it would matter, but any program that can handle UTF-16 should be able to handle either endianness as long as there's a BOM. So again, just send the bytes you get.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Really nice points you highlighted, but in what case should a webserver convert the file endianness?

Comment: For files simply sent from the server to the client, you have no business messing with it at all. They are bytes, nothing else. Just read them, and send them. Job done. The byte order inside the file or inside the sent packets will not be affected by the endianness of the server's CPU, since the file content you are sending are not interpreted integer values, but simple single bytes. And single bytes _have_ no endianness.

Comment: For the record, anyone using UTF16 text files without byte order mark is asking for problems. But detecting text encoding, and, in fact, _any_ processing of the received file content, no matter the type, is completely the client's problem. A server should not mess with that.